# Trouble with Blackmagic Intensity 4k Capture Card

Tags: drivers, video-capture-card

I've cross posted this to the Blackmagic and OBS Studio forums, but I am posting it here as well in case anyone else has any insight.

I have an Intensity 4K capture card installed in a newly built computer.

The actual device I will be capturing from in production is a camcorder HDMI output that I don't have access to right now so I wanted to prove the functionality of the card with a test device. For testing, I have hooked up a Chromecast, a Nintendo Switch, and a Windows 11 laptop via to the HDMI input of the capture card and manually have selected every setting as an option in OBS and have been unable to to get any video signal at all.

I tried a cheap USB to HDMI capture card I had and the Chromecast worked with no changes to settings, so it proves out the functionality of OBS, the operating system, and the Chromecast device. However, in production we will need the Blackmagic card.

I installed the deb packages for Blackmagic Desktop Video Linux 12.3 including Media Express 3.8.

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit.
Linux Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic
OBS Studio: 25.0.3+dfsg1-2.
Blackmagic Video Driver: 12.3

Results of `lspci | grep Blackmagic`:

`04:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Blackmagic Design Intensity Pro 4K`

Results of `lsmod | grep blackmagic`:

`blackmagic_io 1916928 6`

Blackmagic Design System Report shows PCIe Status:
`Link Width 4x, Link Speed 2.5 GT/s`

Anyone have any suggestions about what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I tested by treating the Blackmagic card as an external monitor for a standalone Macbook Pro and the Blackmagic was able to Auto-detect the stream. My suspicion is that there is HDCP enabled on the Nintendo Switch and Chromecast which was blocking the video output, and it is likely that the cheap USB device had native decoding for it.